# Is it Possible to Repair Boot Record on Windows Vista Partition on Dual Boot Ubuntu 12.04.02 LTS Install?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I recently successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04.02 Desktop as a "side-by-side" on an eMachines ET1641-02w PC; which before had Windows Vista; but was no longer bootable, because the boot sector somehow got trashed. After I installed Ubuntu I can go to Devices/OS and I can access all of my docs, pics, videos, music, etc. on the Windows Vista partition; but I still can't "boot" the Windows partition.  I've seen several posts regarding recovering boot sectors using the Boot-repair app; but am wondering if this "boot-repair" is only for the Ubuntu partition.  Can I use "boot-repair" to repair the Windows Vista boot sector?

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience is: no you can't. You need tools from the Windows Vista install disk, not available anywhere due to legal concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your Windows Vista disc and find your way to the CMD on included on the disc.

In the CMD type:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

And if that doesn't work try

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

I must say, I'm unsure whether this will render your Ubuntu unbootable but if you're using GRUB then Windows should have been included in the GRUB boot menu, anyway.

Comment: Cossacksman:  Thanx for the advice.  Unfortunately, when I bought the PC (actually bought two of them identical; one is OK, the other won't boot), it came with Windows Vista pre-installed and didn't come with a Windows Vista disc.  Would it be possible for me to create a Windows Vista "boot DVD" from the "good" PC and try what you suggested?  I know this is more a "Microsoft Support" question, and this is a "Ubuntu" forum; so, thank you for your response.